# Java programs on Windows, Mac and Linux (Unix)

Tags: java, windows, linux, macos, jar

I am working on a Java app which is of course supposed to run on the major operating systems from a usb stick. For the Mac users I bundled the jars (App and updater) into Apple .app programs. Now: what is the best way to let the jars launch each other and use the relative folder path on the stick. I am asking because I noticed that on a Mac it is like the .app folder is the file launched (and not the jar inside) and thus the parent dir is the working directory where all my files will be stored. On Windows and Linux it is just some MyApp.app folder and the files will be inside. 
Is case and path switching by code really the only way to solve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can ask the JVM for the physical location of a given class.  From http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/ClassOrigin.html:

```
// Get the location of this class
Class cls = this.getClass();
ProtectionDomain pDomain = cls.getProtectionDomain();
CodeSource cSource = pDomain.getCodeSource();
URL loc = cSource.getLocation();  // file:/c:/almanac14/examples/
```

This works even for jar-files.

When you know the location, you can navigate from there.

Comment: I would need the location of the Class to do that, or am I getting something wrong? A problem is also that the needed jars inside the .app folder are not in a lib folder, so when starting by console/runtime ClassNotFoundExceptions are thrown.

Comment: I got a workaround by 1. Bundling the .app 2. Going inside the .app and moving the jars into a lib folder 3. Starting by .app doubleclick and by Runtime.getRuntime().exec() works... But this is not pretty :-/

Comment: This sound like you are not doing it the way intended.  You should use the official Apple jar bundler to create a nice bundle.

Comment: Also, the method described, works for classes found on the classpath.  It sound like you have problem getting the classpath set in the first pace.

Comment: So I need to add some class path options when launching the jar from code or a windows .bat?

Comment: No you need to start your JVM with a full, correct classpath unless you know how to write a custom classloader.

Comment: I am confused, the app will be on a stick and I dont know what systems the user will have. Why would/could I start the VM?

Comment: You need to make your distribution usable to all target platform users.  It sounds like you need to read up a bit more on those you are unfamiliar with.  Perhaps Java WebStart could be usable to you?

Comment: No, the app is a bit to large for that (50mb) but I guess there must be a way to add the class path without using a lib folder.

Comment: I just cannot get the classpath to work under windows. The app and lib files are in the same folder, so I use a .bat the calls: java -classpath .;.\MyApp.app\Contents\....\Java\* -jar .\MyApp.app\Contents\....\Java\MyApp.jar But I get a NoClassDefFoundException :(

Comment: Strongly consider making an executable jar so you can just invoke `java -jar MyApp.jar``

Comment: I have but it is inside a subfolder for a windows user because of the jar bundler for mac.

Comment: I ended up, making a launcher for each os. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to create launchers for each of the OSes and from these launchers call the JVM to run jar's. For Linux make a shell script, on Mac it would be .app (or shell script too) and on Windows a .bat or an executable would work.

Comment: Yes, that was my intetion. But these jars need also to "communicate"

Comment: It depends on the application. Normally you would be able to make objects out of the classes from these jars if they are in classpath.